# JSch - execute shell and interact with the execution

Tags: shell, jsch

I need to connect with a machine, execute .sh and give some parameters during the execution. But, after execute .sh and send first parameter, they give me some errors and I don't know what I need to do. How can I interact with .sh execution? HELP!

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class shUnixShell {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        String user = "aaaaa"; 
        String host = "zz.xx.zz.xx"; 
        String passwd = "bbbbb"; 
        int port = 22;
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(passwd);

        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

        channel.connect();
        InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();

        ps.println("ls -ltr");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ps.println("cd /opt/ngin/core/ddesb/ARP/V72");
        Thread.sleep(300);
        ps.println("./Offline_CON.sh");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        ps.println("sp");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("1");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("11971054860");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("n");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("11971054860");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("1");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("60");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("11");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("010");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        ps.println("15");
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        printResult(input, channel);

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * @param input
     * @param channel
     */
    private static void printResult(InputStream input, Channel channel) throws Exception {
        int SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] tmp = new byte[SIZE];
        while (true) {
            while (input.available() > 0) {
                int i = input.read(tmp, 0, SIZE);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse Console:

```
Last login: Thu Aug  3 11:32:20 2017 from 10.125.88.173

ls -ltr


 Active Here

[11:37:10] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ ~]$ ls -ltr
[00mtotal 68
-rwxrwxrwx 1    2760 Mar 30  2016 [01;32mprocessa_consumo_dados_v3.sh.old[00m
-rw-r--r-- 1     174 Abr  1  2016 [00mdesktop.ini[00m
-rw-rw-r-- 1       6 Jun  3  2016 [00mteste.txt[00m
-rw-rw-r-- 1       0 Set  5  2016 [00mLCP[00m
-rw-rw-r-- 1    6616 Set 13  2016 [00mwget-log[00m
-rw-rw-r-- 1    6616 Set 13  2016 [00mwget-log.1[00m
-rw-rw-r-- 1    6616 Set 13  2016 [00mwget-log.2[00m
-rw-rw-r-- 1       0 Set 14  2016 [00ma.out[00m
-rwxrwxrwx 1    3073 Fev  9 14:51 [01;32mprocessa_consumo_dados_v4.sh[00m
-rwxrwxrwx 1    3130 Jul 19 15:34 [01;32mprocessa_raton.sh[00m
-rwxrwxrwx 1   17392 Jul 20 11:21 [01;32mconsumo.sh[00m
drwxrwxrwx 2    4096 Jul 24 15:59 [34;42mft[00m
[m[11:37:10] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ ~]$ 
[11:37:10] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ ~]$ cd /opt/ngin/core/ddesb/ARP/V7 
2
[11:37:11] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ [K
[11:37:11] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ ./Offline_CON.sh
[H[J
--------------------------------
NGIN 14.6*
NOTA - todos os valores indicados por (*), representam o valor
       default de cada funcao, tornando facultativo o input
       de dados

--------------------------------
Informe a regional (mg, base, con, ne, prsc, rjes, rs, sp*): sp

SP
sp
Digite a quantidade de chamadas a serem processadas (1)*: ./Offline_CON.sh: line 75: printf: sp: invalid number
Digite o Numero de A: ./Offline_CON.sh: line 81: [: sp: integer expression expected
./Offline_CON.sh: line 207: printf: sp: invalid number
./Offline_CON.sh: line 209: printf: sp: invalid number
0CONT_SP_20170803113711_0000.dat FCDR_SP.DAT 300
9CONT_AP_20170803113711_0000.dat         000000000##################################
# Arquivo processado com sucesso #
##################################
CONT_SP_20170803113711_sp.dat
##################
Processando chamada de VOZ no SMPC (CON_SP)
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Final do processamento!
##################
# Arquivo de log #
##################
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,604: Service MED_CON_IMPORT_SP [33841]  Started File [CONT_SP_20170803113711_sp.dat] import
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,604: [Service FileToTable] Reading File: CONT_SP_20170803113711_sp.dat
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,915: Total Records: 0
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,915: Total Records OK: 0
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,915: Total Records with Error: 0
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,915: Total Errors:    0
03 Aug 2017 11:37:25,916: Service MED_CON_IMPORT_SP [33841] [324ms]
########################
#Arquivo de Resultados #
########################
1

11971054860

n

11971054860

1

60

11

010

15

SP
CONT_SP_20170803113711_sp.res
cat: /opt/ngin/interfaces/CON/SP/tratados/CONT_SP_20170803113711_sp.res: No such file or directory
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 1
-bash: 1: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 11971054860
-bash: 11971054860: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ n
-bash: n: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 11971054860
-bash: 11971054860: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 1
-bash: 1: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 60
-bash: 60: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 11
-bash: 11: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 010
-bash: 010: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 15
-bash: 15: command not found
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$ 
[11:38:17] [46;37;1m EVL [44;37;1m CAMPINAS [0m  @ V72]$
```

Stackoverflow asking for more information about, but I don't know more what I need to do.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, rather than one channel per command (all over the same transport, so you don't have to authenticate more than once)? Much easier and more sensible -- that way you don't need to detect which output is part of which command or when a command is done by heuristics/pattern-matching, but can just read its stdout and stderr channels until their completion.

Comment: Also, that way you **can't** get the problem you're hitting here (where output is being read by the shell instead of your command), because you get a new input channel specific to each command you're running.

Comment: (Also, it looks like your `Offline_CON.sh` is just buggy, or you're feeding it input other than what it expects, since it's trying to use the `sp` string you enter as if that string were a number).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

Just change:

```
ps.println("ls -ltr");
ps.println("./Hue.sh");
```

For:

```
ps.append("ls -ltr\n");
ps.append("./Hue.sh\n");
```